# ¿Cómo calculo los años bisiestos en php?

Tags: php, date

He intentado hacer una fórmula para calcular los años bisiestos pero parece que no está funcionando y no entiendo muy bien por qué.

```
<?php

    $y = 2019;
    $y = 2020;
    $y = 2300;

    if($y % 4 == 0 and ($y % 100 != 0 and $y % 400 ==0)) echo 'Sí es bisiesto';
    else echo "No es bisiesto";
?>
```

No consigo ver dónde tengo el error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el hecho que PHP ya tiene definido el concepto "año bisiesto" en la librería [`Date`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php), pues admite el carácter *L* como parámetro de cadena para indicar (booleano) si un año es o no bisiesto:

> **L** Si es un año bisiesto   1 si es bisiesto, 0 si no.

Por tanto, simplemente se trata de decir:

```
echo (date('L', strtotime("$y-01-01")) ? 'bisiesto' : 'no bisiesto');
//          ^
```

Lo que es lo mismo que decir:

```
if (date('L', strtotime("$y-01-01")) {
     echo 'bisiesto';
} else {
     echo 'no bisiesto';
}
```

---

Nótese por cierto que tu código sería `$y%4 == 0 && ($y%100 != 0 || $y%400 == 0)`. Es decir, "or" dentro del paréntesis y no "and". Porque no hay ningún número que no sea múltiplo de 100 pero sí lo sea de 400.

Answer (score 4):

Bueno yo lo realizaba de esta forma:

```
if (($y%4 == 0 && $y%100 != 0) || $y%400 == 0)
```

En este caso agrupo `($y%4 == 0 && $y%100 != 0)` y con un or a `$y%400 == 0`

Aunque bueno en tu caso también funciona simplemente con el `or` de la siguiente forma:

```
if ($y%4==0 and ($y%100!=0 or $y%400==0))
```

Comment: Hola Israel,
La función que sugieres da error con algunos años que NO son bisiestos, mirando bien la función me he dado cuenta de que está al revés.
if ($y%4==0 and ($y%100!=0 or $y%400==0)) sería la correcta.

Comment: Perfecto voy a corregirlo, gracias por el aviso ;)

Answer (score 3):

Este fallo le tienes por un error de lógica en el código

```
if($y%4==0 and ($y%100!=0 and $y%400==0))
```

en vez de usar and lo adecuado es or porque lo que buscas es que te muestre si es bisiesto o no Es decir usamos or.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí esta la función, el mismo retorna 1 si es bisiesto el año.

```
function esBisiesto($year=NULL) {
    $year = ($year==NULL)? date('Y'):$year;
    return ( ($year%4 == 0 && $year%100 != 0) || $year%400 == 0 );
}
```