# ¿Como calculo los años bisiestos en php?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando usar este código para calcular años bisiestos  y no consigo ver el error. Me da error porque dice que todos los años son bisiestos.

```
    <php

    $y=  2019;
    $y=  2020;
    $y=  2030;

    if ($y % 4 == 0 and ($y & 100 !=0 and ~y % 400==0)) echo 'Si es bisiesto';
    else echo "No es bisiesto";`introducir el código aquí`
?>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo calculo los años bisiestos en php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/312644/c%c3%b3mo-calculo-los-a%c3%b1os-bisiestos-en-php)

Comment: Tienes un fallo en el código, es un fallo tonto, a mi también me ha pasado, en la wiki se puede leer la función, debería ser así:
if ($y % 4 == 0 and ($y & 100 !=0 or ~y % 400==0))